# Why does this grammar fail to parse this input?

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I'm defining a grammar for a small language and Antlr4. The idea is in that language, there's a keyword "function" which can be used to either define a function or as a type specifier when defining parameters. I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
function aFunctionHere(int a, function callback) ....
```

However, it seems Antlr doesn't like that I use "function" in two different places. As far as I can tell, the grammar isn't even ambiguous.

In the following grammar, if I remove LINE 1, the generated parser parses the sample input without a problem. Also, if I change the token string in either LINE 2 or LINE 3, so that they are not equal, the parser works.

The error I get with the grammar as-is:

> line 1:0 mismatched input 'function' expecting <INVALID>

What does "expecting <INVALID>" mean?

The (stripped down) grammar:

```
grammar test;

begin : function ;

function: FUNCTION IDENTIFIER '(' parameterlist? ')' ;

parameterlist: parameter (',' parameter)+ ;

parameter: BaseParamType IDENTIFIER ;

// Lexer stuff

BaseParamType:
      INT_TYPE
    | FUNCTION_TYPE // <---- LINE 1
    ;

FUNCTION : 'function'; // <---- LINE 2

INT_TYPE : 'int';
FUNCTION_TYPE : 'function'; // <---- LINE 3

IDENTIFIER : [a-zA-Z_$]+[a-zA-Z_$0-9]*;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

The input I'm using:

> function abc(int c, int d, int a)

The program to test the generated parser:

```python
from antlr4 import *
from testLexer import testLexer as Lexer
from testParser import testParser as Parser
from antlr4.tree.Trees import Trees

def main(argv):
    input = FileStream(argv[1] if len(argv)>1 else "test.in")
    lexer =  Lexer(input)
    tokens = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = Parser(tokens)

    tree = parser.begin()

    print Trees.toStringTree(tree, None, parser)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Does it work with the *stripped down* grammar? It's always a good idea to build up the grammar piece-wise, a little bit at a time, then it's very easy to know when and where you introduced an error. And yes, it means you have to simplify the input as well, and build it out as you add to the grammar.

Comment: If I remove the line I marked as "LINE 1" the grammar parses the sample input I posted. But of course, then it wouldn't parse function definitions with parameters of type function, which is what I need.

Comment: By the way, and on an unrelated note, you don't need the `+` in the `IDENTIFIER` regex, doing just `[a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z_$0-9]*` should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use one name for the token `function`.

A token is just a token. Looking at `function` in isolation, it is not possible to decide whether it is a `FUNCTION` or a `FUNCTION_TYPE`. Since `FUNCTION`, comes first in the file, that's what the lexer used. That makes it impossible to match `FUNCTION_TYPE`, so that becomes an invalid token type.

The parser will figure out the syntactic role of the token `function`. So there would be no point using two different lexical descriptors for the same token, even if it would be possible.

In the grammar in the OP, `BaseParamType` is also a lexical type, which will absorb all uses of the token `function`, preventing `FUNCTION` from being recognized in the production for `function`. Changing its name to `baseParamType`, which effectively changes it to a parser non-terminal, will allow the parser to work, although I suppose it may alter the parse tree in undesirable ways.

I understand the objection that the parser "should know" which lexical tokens are possible in context, given the nature of Antlr's predictive parsing strategy. I'm far from an Antlr expert so I won't pretend to explain why it doesn't seem to work, but with the majority of parser generators -- and all the ones I commonly use -- lexical analysis is effectively performed as a prior pass to parsing, so the conversion of textual input into a stream of tokens is done prior to the parser establishing context. (Most lexical generators, including Antlr, have mechanisms with which the user can build lexical context, but IMHO these mechanisms reduce grammar readability and should only be used if strictly necessary.)

Here's the grammar file which I tested:

```
grammar test;  
begin : function ;
function: FUNCTION IDENTIFIER '(' parameterlist? ')' ;
parameterlist: parameter (',' parameter)+ ;
parameter: baseParamType IDENTIFIER ;

// Lexer stuff
baseParamType:
      INT_TYPE
    | FUNCTION //
    ;

FUNCTION : 'function';
INT_TYPE : 'int';
IDENTIFIER : [a-zA-Z_$]+[a-zA-Z_$0-9]*;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Comment: I suppose the change you mention shouldn't be required because a parser has a list of possible next tokens at any given moment. It shouldn't matter if two different tokens have the same text as long as they are not possible next tokens at the same time. Regardless, I made the change you suggested, but it still doesn't work, now I get the following error:

line 1:0 mismatched input 'function' expecting 'function'

Comment: @Gato. Sorry. I didn't notice that `BaseParamType` is also a lexical token. If you change it to `baseParamType` (so that it's a parser token), then the grammar will work (I tested it this time, but not in Python.) I'll try to fix the answer.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Also, you were right, I wrongfully assumed Antlr had a grammar-guided lexing, but it doesn't. I somehow missed the fact that it produces a stream of tokens, regardless of what the grammar expects.